# show search result jquery

Tags: jquery, search

hello I need help on this code, I want to show the divs according to the search variable, which collects it by get with php, but does not search, that is, it shows everything

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var nombres = $('.nombres');
    //var buscando =  buscador.toLowerCase();
    var buscando = buscador.toLowerCase();
    alert(buscando);
    var item = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
        item = $(nombres[i]).html().toLowerCase();
        for (var x = 0; x < item.length; x++) {
            if (buscando.length == 0 || item.indexOf(buscando) > -1) {
                $(nombres[i]).parents('.item').show();

            } else {
                $(nombres[i]).parents('.item').hide();

            }
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is hard to pinpoint the issue with what you provided, I see a possible issue

**You declare x, but don't use it**

In the bit of code below, you are using x to iterate, but never use x, so the code inside the loop does the same thing over and over.

```
for (var x = 0; x < item.length; x++) {
        if (buscando.length == 0 || item.indexOf(buscando) > -1) {
            $(nombres[i]).parents('.item').show();

        } else {
            $(nombres[i]).parents('.item').hide();

        }
    }
```